# Given set of numbers in a string in python

Tags: python, set

I want to check if a set of numbers is present in a string or not

Here is my code:

```
def check_no(string):
    string = string.lower()
    no = set(c)

    s = set()
    for i in string:
        if i in no:
            s.add(i)
        else:
            pass

    if len(s) == len(no):
        return("Valid")
    else:
        return("Not Valid")

c = input()
print(check_no(c))
```

if the given set of numbers is present in the string then it prints `Valid` and if not present it prints `Not valid`

the program works fine when the input is given as `123` and the string is like `I have 12 car and 3 bikes` then the output is valid

but when i give input as `254` and string as `i hav25555number` the output comes as `valid` but the actual output should be `Not valid` as `4` is not present in the string.

Can anyone help how to solve it in the provided code

Comment: Your code is basically taking every character in the string and adds them one by one to a new set of characters. You check if the two sets have the same cardinality number and sure you will get VALID return all the time, it seems.

Comment: @HomayounHamedmoghadam-Rafati No, it's converting `string` to lowercase. If the string contains an uppercase letter which is *not* present as a lowercase letter, then it will *not* return valid since the lowercase version of that character won't be added to s.

Comment: Thanks @Tom, got the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you want to check if all characters match then use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

```
def check_no(text, check):
    valid =  all(character in text for character in check)
    if valid:
        return("Valid")
    else:
        return("Not Valid")

check = '254'
text = 'i hav25555number'
print(check_no(text, check))
```

---

The one-liner version

```
def check_no(text, check):
    return 'Valid' if all(character in text for character in check) else 'Not Valid'
```

Comment: what does all function do here ?

Comment: According to the documentation I linked in my answer it does "Return `True` if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty)". In this case the iterable is a generator that delivers a sequence of `True` and `False` (depending on whether the character is contained in `text`) for each character in `check`. So if all checks are true all will give back `True`.

Comment: Just for fun: `return f"{'Not '[all(character in text for character in check)*4:]}Valid"`

Answer (score 1):

Your function is mostly correct, but probably because of your (terrible) choices of variable names, `string` and `c` variables were mixed up in the environment.

The solution is to add the parameters explicitly to the function definition (also avoid names like `string` or `c` as these could be pre-defined python keywords):

```
teststring = "254"
testc = "i hav25555number"

def check_no(mystring, myc):
    string = mystring.lower()
    no = set(c)
    print("string is",string)
    s = set()
    for i in string:
        
        if str(i) in no:
#            print(i, " in ", no)
            s.add(i)
        else:
            pass
#        print("s is",s)
#        print("no is",no)
    if len(s) == len(no):
        return("Valid")
    else:
        return("Not Valid")

print(check_no(teststring,testc))
```

gives:

```
print(check_no(teststring,testc))
string is 254
Not Valid
```

As mentioned before, you can use `all` to make your code more elegant, although there is nothing wrong with your implementation either.